# How can recurring tasks be stored in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have a rare task that I need to perform manually once every quarter. Performing it takes perhaps ten minutes and automating is seems an overkill so automation will likely never happen and that doesn't hurt at all.

Suppose I want to store this task in TFS. If I make it part of some user story then this user story never ends which sounds bad. It's also unclear how I can make this task surface every quarter and then sink once it's done and wait till the next quarter.

There's an idea to just not store it in TFS but instead create an Outlook reminder whici is an option but I'd prefer to have a recurring task in TFS instead so that all to-do stuff is in one place.

How can recurring tasks be organized and stored in TFS?

Comment: Reconsider automating it or make sure you have a well-trained backup.

Comment: I recommend to google for "tfs recurring tasks". Did you do this? Explain why the solution presented there didn't help you.

Comment: This *was* the first result on Google for `tfs recurring tasks`. Yet another example of why even questions that can be answered by Googling are appropriate on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Define the task something like this:

Instructions:

1. Perform [regular cleanup task].
2. Schedule next cleanup 90 days in the future.

Acceptance criteria:

1. Data are cleaned up
2. Subsequent task exists, is scheduled for 90 days in the future, and is Assigned state